# Trigger for after large upload

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, automation

I have a php page that uploads a txt file into a table,

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt'
                    REPLACE
                    INTO TABLE tempdirtySI
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    ";
```

I want to run a trigger to run after all the data is imported that consists of this code.

```
UPDATE tempdirtysi
SET TIMESTAM = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(TIMESTAM, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
INSERT INTO temploadsi
SELECT * FROM tempdirtysi;
TRUNCATE  tempdirtysi;
```

How do I go about this? I tried to spit the update and the insert into two trigger and that only allows one row to be imported. I also tried to do the update in a php page and have the insert run after update, but that also only runs 1 row.

Maybe there is another way to automate this process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you don't need a trigger for this. Just execute your sql commands sequentially from your PHP code.

```php
$db = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL...';
$db->query($sql);

$sql = 'UPDATE tempdirtysi SET ...';
$db->query($sql);


$sql = 'INSERT INTO temploadsi SELECT * FROM tempdirtysi';
$db->query($sql);


$sql = 'TRUNCATE  tempdirtysi';
$db->query($sql);
```